# After running java app in linux script then return console

Tags: linux

There  is a linux script that contain a statement used to run a java application.
Script (runServer.sh) is like:

```
java ServerApp &
```

Since java application is a server , it keeps running forever until gets stopped. Therefore after running runServer.sh it does not return console automatically and keeps waiting to press return key.

And same problem couses remote script call via Runtime api waiting forever.

```
proc = rt.exec(runScript);
exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

Even When running remote script via ssh say from machine1, crtl+c has to be used to exit from remote script execution.

When I insert following statement into runServer.sh, problem is resolved. But in that case I could not write process id into a file via "echo $? >pid"

```
exec > "\tmp\outlog.txt" 2>&1
```

Is there a way of returning console automatically by modifiying linux script.

Answer (score 0):

Change the script to:

`nohup java ServerApp &`

Comment: Does not work. When execute this statement, it waits me to press return key.

Comment: You may run the script itself with nohup. If this doesn't work I'm stumped.